# About some Bachmann–Landau notations

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Let $(u_{n})_{n},(v_{n})_{n}$ two strictly positive real sequences verifying the following property:
There exist a positive integer $N$ and there exist a positive real number a such that for all $n>N$ we have 
$$u_{n}/v_{n}≤a$$
I am asking if there is any obstruction to write
$$u_{n}/v_{n}≤a⇔1/a≤v_{n}/u_{n}$$
This question is related to this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, then it holds that

$$ x \le y \iff \frac{1}{y} \le \frac{1}{x}.$$